# Can PhpStorm resolve mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess when doing code analysis?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpstorm

I have a bunch of mod_rewrite rules in my PHP project. When I commit to git PhpStorm runs a code analysis on what I'm committing, which is great, but it produces a bunch of warnings because links point to the rewritten URLs, not the actual PHP files, for example:

```
Warning:(103, 71) Cannot resolve file 'contact'
```

For a link like this:

```
<a href="/contact">get in touch</a>
```

Is there a way to make PhpStorm resolve the rewrite rules in my .htaccess file? Failing that, how do I turn this inspection off? I've tried unchecking `Preferences > Editor > Inspections > HTML > Anchor reference problems` but I'm still getting the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make PHPStorm resolve the rewrite rules in my .htaccess file?

No.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1032 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

> Failing that, how do I turn this inspection off? I've tried unchecking Preferences > Editor > Inspections > HTML > Anchor reference problems but I'm still getting the warnings.

Correct one is **"Inspections | HTML | File reference problems"**

Comment: The specified ticket is now in a "Verified" state.